# More TextBlocks or Use StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

What is better and more faster solution?

This:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="(" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text=")" />
</StackPanel>
```

Or this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat=({0})}" />
```

Comment: The second one is better obviously!

Comment: @S.Akbari why? Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: @Pikoh...Because of using just one `TextBlock` instead of three useless `TextBlocks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As S.Akbari already said, the second one is better.

Adding additional UI elements always increases the load on rendering. WPF has to figure out how to arrange them, what size they need, what size they can get, and so on.

You won't see a difference with just 3 `TextBlock`s, but if you have thousands of them it will have an impact.

Comment: This is it what i needed to know. Thanks!